# ¿Cuándo se estableció "izquierda" como sustituto de "siniestra" en el español?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, historia, adjetivos

Hoy día, tenemos en español las siguientes palabras:

- **[derecha](http://dle.rae.es/?id=CGv2o6x)**: del latín *directus*.
- **[izquierda](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MFY7k4v)**: del vasco *ezkerra* 'izquierda'.

Me llama la atención que *izquierda* se haya tomado del vasco, un idioma con muchos menos hablantes que el latín, del cual proviene *[siniestra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XyrEzmC)*, que también se recoge pero es mucho menos usada.

Entiendo que la acepción de la mano "siniestra" como "la mano del demonio", que se promulgaba por parte de la Iglesia hasta no hace mucho tuvo algo que ver, y puede que también eso haya tenido que ver con las otras acepciones que tiene hoy en día la palabra *siniestro*.

En todo caso, quería preguntar si realmente la Iglesia tuvo algo que ver con la, digamos, degradación de la palabra *siniestro, tra*. Y como pregunta principal: ¿cuándo se introdujo la palabra *izquierda* en nuestro idioma? ¿Hacia qué siglo había suplantado ya a *siniestra* como palabra predominante? ¿Se sabe por qué se escogió una palabra del vasco para tal fin?

Comment: Yo me pregunto porque tampoco se dice *diestra* de la misma manera. Solo nos queda la locución «a diestra y siniestra»

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En las sociedades primitivas es muy habitual que las palabras que se refieren a ciertas cosas malas, una vez que sus connotaciones se hacen muy claras, sean reemplazadas por otras. Las palabras originales cambian de significado, en sentido peyorativo, o bien no se las pronuncia más (se vuelven tabú).

El lado izquierdo está asociado desde tiempos inmemoriales con lo incorrecto, lo malo, lo diabólico, etc., y por lo tanto las palabras que refieren a este lado son candidatas seguras al cambio.

Muestra de esto es que las palabras para "izquierda" en muchas lenguas cercanamente emparentadas tengan formas y orígenes totalmente diferentes. El castellano tomó *izquierda* del vasco (por qué es imposible saberlo hoy, pero en todo caso estaba disponible y no se parecía fonéticamente a la palabra temida); el francés formó *gauche* a partir de *[gauchir](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gauchir#French)*, con el significado de "torcer, doblar, esquivar, actuar engañosamente"; el inglés reemplazó el término *winstre* (a su vez muy posiblemente producto de un tabú anterior) por *[left](https://www.etymonline.com/word/left)*, del inglés antiguo **lyft* "débil, flojo, tonto"; en alemán tenemos *[link](https://www.dwds.de/wb/links#et-1)*, que puede provenir de una raíz indoeuropea que denota "flojo, cojo, tullido".

Según un comentario que [leo en un blog](https://www.delcastellano.com/etimologia-siniestro-izquierda/), aunque sin una fuente, en tiempos del *Mío Cid* ya podría verse *izquierda*, pero todavía se la consideraría un barbarismo, prefiriéndose la palabra romance original *siniestra*. En el CORDE aparece *esquierdo* en un texto anónimo de mediados del siglo XIII, *esquierda* en Abraham de Toledo (1250), y ya con la ortografía actual hay un puñado de registros *c.* 1300.

Comment: ¿Crees entonces que se podría decir que "izquierda" es un eufemismo de "siniestra"?

Comment: También del vascuence son *esquerdo* en portugués y *esquerre* en catalán, y otras versiones semejantes en los demás idiomas ibéricos. El portugués tiene *canhoto* (dicho como si fuera “cañoto”) en vez de *zurdo* en castellano, y tienen varias palabras derivadas que pueden usarse en vez de *esquerdo* como *canhestro*, *canhestrice*, &c. Sin embargo, igual como en castellano los portugueses mantienen antiguas palabras latinas como *sinistra* y aun *sestra/destra*, pero son más comunes *esquerda* o a veces *canhota*.

Comment: Sí, de hecho al referirme al español debería haber dicho "romance ibérico", puesto que en la época de que se trata la cosa no estaba claramente dividida como hoy… *Zurdo* tampoco tiene cognados romances, dicho sea de paso (el DLE dice que es "de origen prerrománico").