# Acerca de la etimología de niño

Tags: etimología, historia

Revisando la etimología de niño, aparece en el DLE como

> [**niño, ña**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QW5mMvv)
>   De la voz infantil *ninno*.

y en otros sitios que la voz es del latín vulgar. El término como tal en español, aparece escrito al menos desde hace poco menos de 800 años como muestra el [Libro de la infancia y muerte de Jesús](http://www.cervantesvirtual.com/servlet/SirveObras/02582785400247240759079/p0000001.htm#5). Sin embargo llama la atención que términos similares se usan solo en unas cuantas lenguas bastante cercanas entre las romances (asturiano o gallego por ej.), en otras lenguas se utiliza más el *infante* (término del latín culto), el *bambino* italiano, el *nen* catalán, o en un idioma más 'cercano' el *criança* portugués.

Se me hace curioso que si el término viene del latín vulgar solo sobreviva en pocas lenguas. ¿Pueden ayudarme para confirmar el origen del vocablo en español?

Comment: El _nen_ catalán que mencionas tiene el mismo origen. También el malloquín _nin_, el lombardo y napolitano _ninno_ y el portugués _menino_ (el mismo de Las Meninas de Velásquez). En realidad, no es tan aislado.

Comment: @Rodrigo, so pena de sonar más papista que el papa, ¿*nen* no sería más común a *nene*? aunque nene y niño son sinónimos muy próximos, pero la consulta breve no le da el origen latino a la palabra nene, la deja como voz infantil. Y aunque eso iría en otra pregunta, ¿las voces infantiles no entran como onomatopeyas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Palabras 'comunes' no tienen que ser cognados en todas las lenguas romances. Tomemos, por ejemplo, *izquierda*:

[image]

No obstante, los cognados de *niño* sí existen en varios otros idiomas con una definición similar (*chico, hijo, infante*):

- `Latín vulgar` *ninus

  - `Castellano antiguo` *ninno

    - `Castellano` niño
  - `Lombardo` ninno
  - `Napolitano` ninno
  - `Aragonés` nino, ninno
  - `Mirandés` nino
  - `Italiano` nino
  - `Galiciano` neno
  - `Sardo` nennu
  - `Asturiano` neñu, ñeñu
  - `Leonés` neñu
  - `Catalán` nen, nin

Y posiblemente también estas palabras:

- `Latín vulgar` *ninus (?)

  - `Portugués antiguo` meninho, meninno, menynno, menỹo

    - `Galiciano` meniño, miniño
    - `Portugués` menino, minino

      - `Castellano` menino

        - `Francés` menin

---

[image]

---

<sup>• https://www.reddit.com/r/etymologymaps/comments/46x4f0/the_word_child_in_european_languages/</sup>
<sup>• https://www.reddit.com/r/etymologymaps/comments/4i5b7e/the_word_boy_in_the_romance_languages_of_italy/</sup>
<sup>• https://www.reddit.com/r/etymologymaps/comments/5d53gq/etymology_map_for_the_word_left_in_europe_oc/</sup>

Comment: el caso de izquierda que mencionas, el hecho que no sea de origen latino en español ayuda un poco (el debate a profundidad lo planteo @Charlie [https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23081/cu%C3%A1ndo-se-estableci%C3%B3-izquierda-como-sustituto-de-siniestra-en-el-espa%C3%B1ol], pero de momento el ver que existen palabras similares en el ámbito latino da algo de sostén a que venga del latín vulgar, no que sea solo una voz infantil

Comment: Esta respuesta ha sido una de las ganadoras del [concurso de nominaciones a la mejor respuesta / Best answer nominations (2018 Q1)](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2883/5481)