# ¿Por qué en español decimos "zorro" en vez de un derivado del latín "vulpes"?

Tags: etimología, historia, animales

En general los nombres españoles de los animales que han vivido desde antiguo en Europa provienen de las palabras latinas correspondientes. Es el caso de las vacas, gatos, cabras, ovejas, serpientes, caballos, burros, etc., que son etimológicamente derivados del latín.

No es el caso del [**zorro**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cVU9wGT), que según el DRAE proviene del portugués:

> Del port. *zorro* 'holgazán', der. de *zorrar* 'arrastrar'; cf. occit. *mandra* 'zorra'; propiamente 'mandria, holgazán'.

Pues me parece raro que no se use (o no exista) alguna denominación derivada de "vulpes", que era la palabra latina con que se designaba este animalito. Y de hecho tampoco se usa en catalán (*guineu*), gallego (*raposo*), francés (*renard*), occitano (*guèine, mandra, rainal*) ni portugués (*raposa*).

¿Por qué será que, a diferencia del resto de los animales, se ha preferido un juego de palabras ("holgazán") en vez de continuar usando una palabra ya existente ("vulpes")? Y eso con el agregado de que el juego de palabras se tomó de un tercer idioma, el portugués. Es rebuscado.

Comment: Qué gracia, en catalán llamamos _mandra_ a la pereza y en este caso la [etimología oficial](http://www.diccionari.cat/lexicx.jsp?GECART=0085759) explica que viene del italiano _mandra_ (que parece querer decir tanto _rebaño_ como _vago_), que vendría del griego _mándra_ (que querría decir _lecho del ganado, establo_). Vaya, que esta relación entre zorro y pereza parece venir de lejos.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

La razón es así: muchos nombres de animales solían ser palabras tabú. La gente tenía miedo de llamar a los animales salvajes y destructivos por sus nombres "reales" y los sustituían por otros que existían, incluyendo el zorro:

- [OUP blog: *‘Vulpes vulpes,’ or foxes have holes.* Part 1](https://blog.oup.com/2016/03/animal-name-origins-taboo-words-noa-fox-etymology/), [Part 2](https://blog.oup.com/2016/03/fox-etymology-word-origin/), Anatoly Liberman

> Our ancient ancestors were [so worried about bears, they didn't even want to name them because they feared [the bears] might overhear and come after them.](https://xkcd.com/2381/) So they came up with this word — this is up in Northern Europe — bruin, meaning "the brown one" as a euphemism, and then bruin segued into bear. We know the euphemism, but we don't know what word it replaced, so bear is the oldest-known euphemism.
>
> - [Euphemania: Our Love Affair with Euphemisms](https://content.time.com/time/arts/article/0,8599,2041313,00.html)

No obstante, sí hay un cognado en castellano de *vulpes*:

> [**vulpeja**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c5nldWp)
> Del lat. *vulpecŭla*, dim. de *vulpes* 'raposa'.
>
> 1. `f.` [zorra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cVU9wGT) (‖ mamífero).

y un latinismo culto [del siglo XVIII](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vulp%C3%A9cula&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3) de la misma raíz:

> [**vulpécula**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c5lHtJH)
> Del lat. *vulpecŭla*, dim. de *vulpes* 'raposa'.
>
> 1. `f.` [vulpeja.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c5nldWp)

---

Como notas, en muchos de los idiomas romances de Francia e Iberia se usan eufemismos o préstamos de otros idiomas para su(s) palabra(s) para *zorro*:

1. De origen incierto - zorro (esp)
2. [Del lat. *mamphur*](http://www.dom-en-ligne.de/dom.php?lhid=4scE0AMIfH8bxAc7zBoRIy) - mandra (occ)
3. a) [Del germànic **wihsela**](http://dcvb.iec.cat/results.asp?word=guilla) - guilla (cat)
   b) [Del germànic **Winald** / **Winihild**](http://dcvb.iec.cat/results.asp?word=guineu) - guineu (cat), guèine (occ)
4. Del lat. *rapum* 'nabo' - rabosa (esp. ant.), raposo (esp), raposo (gal), raposa (pt), raposu, rapiegu (ast), rabosa, raboso (arg), rabosa (cat)
5. [Roman de Renart](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_de_Renart) - renard (fr), r'nard (norman), rinåd, rnåd (walloon), rainal, rainald, [rainard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ywj0K-oRc5A) (occ), <s>renard</s> (cat), renar, ראפוזה, רינאר (ladino)

Sin embargo (unos dialectos de) gallego y occitano sí todavía usan una palabra derivada de *vulpes*, como la mayoría de los idiomas romances del este de Francia:

6. a) From Latin vulpēs - golpe (gal), <s>volp</s> (cat), vop (occ), volp (lombard), bolp, bolpe, volp, volpe (venetian), bolp, volp (friulian), volp (ladin), vulp, vualp, vuolp, uolp, golp, gualp (romansch), bualp, vualp (dalmatian), bulpo (istriot), volpe (it), vórpa, vorpe (neapolitan), vurpi, jurpi, gurpi, vulpi (sicilian), volpe (corsican), grupi, gurpe (sard), vulpi, vulpe (aromanian)

Y los **diminutivos** de *vulpes* en muchas de las lenguas galo-ibéricas parecen haber sobrevivido ilesos:

6. b) [image]

---

<sup>**Nota:** la etimología de *zorro* provista en el DLE es poco fiable:</sup>

> <sup>"The initial attestations of Sp. *zorro/zorra* 'fox' are from the mid fifteenth century and appear almost exclusively in the feminine, employed in *cancionero* poetry, with reference to idle, immoral women (cf. mod. *zorra* 'prostitute'). […] DCECH may well be right in stating that *zorro/zorra* secondarily became a euphemistic designation for the dreaded fox (cf. *raposo* so used). […] The late initial documentation of *zorro* leads to the question [of] whether this word goes back to early Roman Spain or whether it is a later borrowing from Basque, a derivation, as noted above, challenged by Trask (1997: 421). Far from convincing is the unprovable hypothesis in DCECH that *zorro* goes back to a verb *zorrar* (whose authenticity I have been unable to verify), allegedly on onomatopoeic origin."</sup>

> - <sup>*A History of the Spanish Lexicon: A Linguistic Perspective,* 2012 (p. 39)</sup>

Comment: El artículo que citas (www.blog.oup.com ...) y su hipótesis (La razón es así: muchos nombres de animales solían ser palabras tabú. La gente tenía miedo de llamar a los animales salvajes y destructivos por sus nombres "reales" y los sustituían por otros que existían) puede que sea cierto para el inglés, pero no para el español:  **oso** y **lobo** proceden del latin *ursum* y *lupus*, sin más.

Comment: @user19585 no entiendo el problema - esto es un fenómeno bien documentado en casi cada lengua de Europa. No dice que debe pasar con el nombre de cada animal silvestre, o que el conjunto de animales que habrían cambiado sus nombres es el mismo en cada lengua; solo que ha pasado con *este* animal en castellano.

Comment: Leo en otra parte que los nombres de entes poderosos podían usarse también como nombres protectores o que apelaban al poder del animal, en vez de suprimirse como tabú. Todo depende de cuáles hayan sido las creencias particulares del lugar. Los nombres Urso, Úrsula (del latín *ursus*), o Wulfilas, Wolfgang (del germánico *wolf-*) son ejemplos de esto.

Answer (score 8):

Cito a continuación la entrada para *zorro* del *Breve diccionario etimológico* de Corominas (negritas mías):

> ZORRA, ZORRO, 'raposa, -o', med. S. XV. Probablemente el sentido primitivo fue 'mujer u hombre holgazanes', S. XIII (de donde luego *zorra* 'ramera', 1616), significado vivo todavía en portugués y aplicado popularmente a la [raposa](http://dle.rae.es/?id=V9crmPm) en son de vituperio. [...] En su sentido originario el vocablo derivará del antiguo y portugués *zorrar* 'arrastrar', 2º cuarto S. XV, onomatopeya del roce del que se arrastra perezosamente. ***Zorra* reemplazó a *raposa*, como éste había sustituido el más antiguo *vulpeja* (lat. *vulpes*), por la repugnancia del campesino a llamar por su nombre tradicional a este animal maléfico, lo que le conduce constantemente a buscar nuevos nombres indirectos y figurados para llamarle.**

Por lo que estamos ante un nuevo caso de eufemismo que acabó incorporándose al idioma, como pasó con [la palabra *izquierda*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23081/12637) que, al contrario que *derecha* que deriva directamente del latín, se originó a partir de la palabra vasca *ezkerra* como eufemismo de *siniestra* por sus connotaciones.

Answer (score 4):

Me parece que es mucho más sencillo.
ZORRO es piel en Euskera, 
MoZORRO es como se llama a los disfraces del carnaval rural, a base de pieles de animales que aún hoy se pueden ver, no solo en Euskal Herria ,sino en muchos carnavales rurales europeos, y que tienen reminiscencias de las antiguas culturas chamánicas -animistas, donde los animales eran totems o símbolos mágicos y referentes para ciertos clanes.

El Zorro es llamado así por su piel (zorroa)

Comment: Derivado de zorro (piel ) es también la palabra zurrón (zorro on, ) bolsa de piel que llevaban los pastores.

Comment: La frase "vas hecho unos zorros también hace referencia a quienes vestian con harapos o pieles, gente de las montañas vastidas con ZORROS o pieles

Comment: ¡Qué pista tan buena! Considera incluir tus comentarios posteriores en la propia pregunta, utilizando el botón [edit]. También va bien proporcionar referencias, para fijar tu razonamiento en base a la pregunta formulada. Gracias y bienvenido/a a [spanish.se] :)

Answer (score 0):

En vasco "zurr" quiere decir "atento, listo".
Suponiendo una adaptación así:

```
ZO(U)RR + A (artículo vasco) / O (artículo castellano)
```

Tendríamos ZORRA o ZORRO que podría ser el origen de la palabra en castellano.

Answer (score 0):

See also the following paper : 
https://www.academia.edu/14252280/ZORRO._Origen_etimol%C3%B3gico_fijado_por_Enrique_Cabrejas

The author claims that *zorro* comes from Iberian words ZO + RO meaning "to be smart".

Answer (score 0):

Estoy de acuerdo que "zorro" pueda provenir del vasco. "Zorrar" no existe en portugués. Sí que existe "azorrar" y ese proviene de "zorro" y no el revés. En cuanto a la palabra occitana "mandre, mandra", no tiene nada que ver con esp. "mandría". Verdad que parece mucho a la palabra catalana "mandra" ( = pereza) pero "mandra" en catalán no tiene el significado de "zorro" y tampoco la palabra occitana tiene la de "pereza". No son iguales. En gascón, para decir "zorro", tenemos la palabra renard (del francés), var. arnard, también (la) vop (lat. vulpes) y mandre-a (zorro -a). Esta última voz podría ser un celtismo cf. irlandés madra: perro, madra rua : zorro (lit. perro rojo). El étimo és matu- qui significa oso. cf. galés: hwn madog = zorro (lit. perro úrsido) (< cuon madāko), hyn madyn=  zorro (lit. perro úrsido) (< cuon madano). Suposadamente *mádara >  (la) mandra > (lo) mandre.