# ¿Se debe poner un "ni" antes de cada elemento de una enumeración?

Tags: puntuación, conjunciones, redundancia

Escribe [Rodrigo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/6915/rodrigo) en [¿Por qué en español decimos "zorro" en vez de un derivado del latín "vulpes"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/26494/1674):

> Y de hecho tampoco se usa en catalán (*guineu*), gallego (*raposo*), francés (*renard*), occitano (*guèine, mandra, rainal*) ni portugués (*raposa*).

Acortando, sería algo así como:

> Y de hecho tampoco se usa en catalán, gallego, francés, occitano ni portugués.

Y la verdad es que me suena un poco raro. ¿No debería escribirse la conjunción *ni* antes de cada uno de los elementos, o al menos antes del primero?

Comment: @aparente001 ¿a qué obedece esta nueva etiqueta? No creo que sea necesaria ni ayude demasiado a clasificar ni a encontrar.

Comment: En la pregunta, estás preguntando si se puede eliminar el uso quizás redundante de *ni*.  Hay otras preguntas que tratan de la posible redundancia.  The better our tagging system, the easier it is to find stuff.  My memory is atrocious.  I really lean on tags to help me find things.

Comment: Ejemplos de preguntas candidatas para esta etiqueta: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=redundant

Comment: @aparente001 no creo que califique nada, como sí hacen [tag:gramática], [tag:subjuntivo] o [tag:puerto-rico]. Es una etiqueta tan transversal que no creo que ayude a clasificar.

Comment: I read that redundancy is a grammatical feature of Spanish.  But if you feel strongly about it just go ahead and get rid of it.  (If I absent-mindedly recreate it at some point, you should remind me that you nixed it earlier.  My memory just keeps getting worse and worse.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, no y no.

Dice el DPD en su artículo [*coma*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=V1EqcYbX4D61AWBBrd):

> 1.2. Para separar o aislar elementos u oraciones dentro de un mismo enunciado
>
> 1.2.1. La coma separa los elementos de una enumeración, siempre que estos no sean complejos y ya contengan comas en su expresión, pues, en ese caso, se utiliza el punto y coma (→ punto y coma, 3a): Ayer me compré dos camisas, un pantalón, una chaqueta y dos pares de zapatos.
>
> **Cuando la enumeración es completa o exhaustiva, el último elemento va introducido por una conjunción (y, e, o, u, ni), delante de la cual no debe escribirse coma**:
>
> *Es un chico muy reservado, estudioso y de buena familia.
>
> No le gustan las manzanas, las peras ni los plátanos.
>
> ¿Quieres té, café o manzanilla?*

Comment: @walen Me da la sensación que el uso en cada elemento responde a una intención enfática: _No voy ni yo, ni él, ni nadie_ suena más contundente que _No voy, él ni nadie_. También me pica la curiosidad saber cuándo debe repetirse la partícula que los introduce: _no se usa en catalán, gallego, francés..._ respecto _no se usa en catalán, en gallego, en francés..._.

Comment: Cuando lo haces adrede se llama [polisíndeton](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polis%C3%ADndeton)

Comment: tomalo de esta manera: el "ni" es el "y" en negativo